# CryptoJS to OpenSSL encryption conversion

Tags: javascript, c, encryption, openssl, cryptojs

I need to port some JavaScript code to a C99 backend. In the Javascript code they use CryptoJS to perform AES encryption:

```
var key = CryptoJS.MD5(Math.random().toString()).toString();
key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);

var iv = CryptoJS.MD5(Math.random().toString()).toString();
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);

var data = "testdata";
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, { iv:iv, mode:CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding:CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding });
```

Now I need to implement the same code in C with the OpenSSL library. I have created the random MD5 strings without problem but I cannot see how to implement the AES encryption with zero padding. This is what I have:

```
bool crypto_aes_encrypt(const char* data, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char **out_buf, int *out_buf_len)
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf();

    /* Initialize the cipher context */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if(!ctx) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Initialize the AES encryption */
    if(EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv) != 1) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Encrypt the data */
    *out_buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(2048 * sizeof(char));
    *out_buf_len = 0;
    if(EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, *out_buf, out_buf_len, (const unsigned char*) data, strlen(data)) != 1) {
        free(out_buf);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, *out_buf + *out_buf_len, out_buf_len) != 1) {
        free(out_buf);
        return NULL;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    return true;
}
```

How can I implement the ZeroPadding in OpenSSL which is used in CryptoJS?

Comment: Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. It has a brief section on padding. Th short of it is, if you disable PKCS padding, then you have to handle the padding yourself. In the case of zero padding, you are responsible for zero'ing tail bytes before encrypting a block. Also see [Zero Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding).

Comment: I'm very close now. The start of the encrypted output string is the same, but OpenSSL adds some extra bytes at the end.

Comment: Be sure its really OpenSSL adding the bytes; and not you leaving tail bytes unintialized. Remember, block ciphers always work on a block. In the case of AES, its 16 bytes per block.

Comment: I got it working. I was encrypting an extra 16B null-byte block with OpenSSL which was off course not required. Thanks for the help jww.

Comment: Very good. Be sure to post an answer and accept it when the time limit passes. I try to upvote questions and answer that promote interop. Early on, it was not clear to me where the question was going. Now that the answer has arrived, its clear to me this is a quality Q&A.